# File operation using numpy

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I am trying to delete phrase from text file using numpy.I have tried
num = [] and num1.append(num1)
'a' instead of 'w' to write the file back.
While append doesn't delete the phrase
writes' first run deletes the phrase
second run deletes second line which is not phrase
third run empties the file

```
import numpy as np

phrase = 'the dog barked'

num = 0 

with open("yourfile.txt") as myFile:
    for num1, line in enumerate(myFile, 1):
        if phrase in line:
            num += num1
        else:
            break 
            

a=np.genfromtxt("yourfile.txt",dtype=None, delimiter="\n", encoding=None ) 

      
with open('yourfile.txt','w') as f:    
    for el in np.delete(a,(num),axis=0):
        f.write(str(el)+'\n')


'''
the bird flew
the dog barked
the cat meowed
'''
```

Comment: So you want to delete any line in the file that contain the `phrase` string, right? instead of just deleting the `phrase` string

Comment: Your first loop only examines lines until one doesn't contain your `phrase`. If a line it looks at doesn't contain the string, it `break`s out of the loop. You probably need to get rid of the `else: break` block in addition to fixing up whatever your numpy issue is. I'm not sure I understand what it's trying to do, so I can't give an answer about that part.

Comment: Why are you using `numpy`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can still use `nums.append(num1)` with `w` mode, the issue I think you're getting is that you used the `enumerate` function for `myFile`'s lines using 1-index instead of 0-index as expected in numpy array. Changing it from `enumerate(myFile, 1)` to `enumerate(myFile, 0)` seems to fix the issue

```
import numpy as np

phrase = 'the dog barked'

nums = [] 

with open("yourfile.txt") as myFile:
    for num1, line in enumerate(myFile, 0):
        if phrase in line:
            nums.append(num1)

a=np.genfromtxt("yourfile.txt",dtype=None, delimiter="\n", encoding=None ) 
      
with open('yourfile.txt','w') as f:
    for el in np.delete(a,nums,axis=0):
        f.write(str(el)+'\n')
```